# Version of Stage and Gazebo in Diamondback

Tags: gazebo, simulation, stage, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone

Which version of Stage (I think it is 3.2.2 - not sure) and Gazebo are used in Diamondback (ROS 1.4.8).

Is there a command line facility to find it out ?

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11009/version-of-stage-and-gazebo-in-diamondback/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-08-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for Gazebo, Diamondback uses a patched [gazebo wg branch](https://playerstage.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/playerstage/code/gazebo/branches/wg/) [r8967](http://playerstage.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/playerstage/code/gazebo/branches/wg/?pathrev=8967).  More details can be found in the [ros makefile](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/diamondback/gazebo/Makefile.gazebo.tarball).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-08-24**:
@hsu  : Hey John ! .... thank you for that, branch r8967 would be gazebo ver. 0.10 ? Anything for Stage ? Any quick command line for the job ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both Diamondback and Electric provide Stage 3.2.2 with a small patch applied.  We're planning to upgrade to Stage 4.x for Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2